# Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int While selecting rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Expense_monthly_report] @start_date VARCHAR(100), 
                                           @end_date   VARCHAR(100) 
AS 
    BEGIN 
      DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(max) 
      DECLARE @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(max) 

      SET nocount ON; 

      SELECT @PivotColumns = COALESCE(@PivotColumns + ',', '') 
                         + Quotename( date_of_expp) 
      FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT Month(date_of_exp) AS date_of_expp 
              FROM   [dbo].[tbl_exp_details] 
              WHERE  date_of_exp >= @start_date 
                     AND date_of_exp <= @end_date) AS PivotExample 

      SET @SQLQuery = N'SELECT  p.part_id,' + @PivotColumns 
                + ',total_amount      FROM (SELECT part_id,month(date_of_exp) as month_of_exp,exp_amount FROM [dbo].[tbl_exp_details]) as tbl PIVOT( sum(exp_amount) FOR month_of_exp IN (' 
                + @PivotColumns 
                + ')) AS P join (SELECT  part_id,sum(exp_amount) as total_amount      FROM [dbo].[tbl_exp_details] where date_of_exp>=' 
                + @start_date + ' and date_of_exp<=' + @end_date 
                + ' group by part_id) as la on p.part_id=la.part_id' 

      EXEC Sp_executesql @SQLQuery 
    END
```

I am getting error

> date incompatible with int

. Help me to find out the problem.

Comment: Going to probably need some table structure (column types) and possibly sample data to give you a definitive answer otherwise it's going to be speculation.

Comment: Check the `@SQLQuery` string, you concat both `@start_date` and `end_date` without quotes.

Comment: Tip: when you build a query and it doesn't work: print the string you are trying to execute. Missing qotes are difficult to see in a string expression

Answer (score 1):

You have not delimited the date values in the dynamic query.

So

```
date_of_exp<=' + @end_date
```

becomes

```
date_of_exp<= 2017-07-19
```

which evaluates to this, and int won't implicitly convert to date

```
date_of_exp <= 1991
```

The correct way to use Sp_executesql and fix this is:

```
SET @SQLQuery = N'SELECT  p.part_id,' + @PivotColumns 
                + ',total_amount      FROM (SELECT part_id,month(date_of_exp) as month_of_exp,exp_amount FROM [dbo].[tbl_exp_details]) as tbl PIVOT( sum(exp_amount) FOR month_of_exp IN (' 
                + @PivotColumns 
                + ')) AS P join (SELECT  part_id,sum(exp_amount) as total_amount FROM [dbo].[tbl_exp_details] where date_of_exp>= @start_date and date_of_exp<=@end_date '
                + ' group by part_id) as la on p.part_id=la.part_id' 

  EXEC Sp_executesql @SQLQuery, 
          N'@start_date date, @end_date date', 
          @start_date,
          @end_date
```

Comment: I want to add a single row at last which calculate the sum of every month.